# Any good books for studying Continued Fraction?

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions

Does anyone have recommendations for cheap books on Continued Fractions? I do not have much money and so it needs to be a cheap book.

Comment: Continued Fractions by Khinchin published by Dover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a book exactly but free if you have access: [Y.T. Cheng’s undergraduate thesis on continued fractions](http://www.math.cornell.edu/m/sites/default/files/imported/Research/SeniorTheses/2007/chengYTThesis.pdf).