# How to recover a number from approximation

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory, diophantine-approximation

How can I recover a number $n$ from its approximation $a$.

For example, if $n$ is $1.09861228866$, then $a$ can be $1.099$($N$ approximated value).

How can I implement a function $F$ that takes $a$, and possibly some other variables to output $n$.

**My method**

I find the percentage error $p$ of $a$ in reference to $n$. Then I define $F$ to take $a$, and $p$ as inputs.

With $p$, $F$ calculate the error $e$(the difference between $a$ and $n$), and adjust $a$ with $e$ to output $n$

**The problem with my method**

Sometimes the output of $F$ is very far from $n$ due to the fact that I also approximate the percentage error $p$.

Please how can I define $F$ better so that $F$ will always output $n$ when given $a$

And please note that all variables that $F$ takes will always be approximated to $x$ decimal places.

I've also read online that the probability of a question being ignored/down-voted here is very high, but please, if you will down vote this question, please give some pointers for a solution to this problem.

I really need to to define $F$. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

*according to @lulu*,

> You can't recover n from its approximation, you've lost information. If you have something more specific in mind please add detail

Yeah I understand that approximating $n$ results to loss of information. That is why I used percentage error to define the lost information in my method. But the percentage error is not always effective, that's why I'm looking for a more effective way to represent the lost information.

Comment: You can't recover $n$ from its approximation, you've lost information.  If you have something more specific in mind please add detail.

Comment: To be clear: for this to be answerable you must have more information than just $a$.  If, say, you are given $a$ and $n-a$ then of course you can do it.  But usually one approximates a number precisely because the raw number carries more information that you require, so you discard the excess.  If I ask you what time it is, I generally don't mean "to the nearest nanosecond".  But if you tell me "it's around noon" I can't mathematically compute the nearest nanosecond.  That information is lost.

Comment: Post edit;  I am still not clear what you are hoping for.  If you wish to retain the full value of $n$, then why not do exactly that?   True, you could also take some approximation, $a$ and then retain the additive error $n-a$, or with some restrictions, the multiplicative error, $\frac {n-a}a$ or similar algebraic expressions.  But, again, it's simpler to just retain $n$.

Comment: *I find the percentage error* $p$ *of* $a$ *in reference to* $n$. --- This requires the approximation error to be measured by percentage error. What if the approximation error is measured by something else, such as absolute error, logarithmic error, some kind of iterated logarithmic error, truncation error (if expressed in radix form to some base), etc.?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you added context.  In what situation is $n$ observed?  What is to be done with that value?  How is the approximation determined and what tells you that your approximation is "good enough"?  And so on.

Comment: Dave. Thanks. I'm embarrassed to say I'm only aware of percentage error. I will look into the other error definition topics you listed in your comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Until you tell us exactly what kind of problem you have, we can't possibly help you. Sorry, but that is the way it is. You have given us **zero** details as of yet. It is impossible to guess what your real problem is.

Comment: @ lulu, Let's say the number $n$ is in $1000$ decimal places, I need to save it in a space that is limited to $5$ digits, then $n$ will be approximated to $5$ significant figures. But I will also have to recover $n$ from the approximated value, and possibly some other values that represent the lost information(such as percentage error) some day

Comment: Please Dave. It's not a must the approximation error should be measured by percentage error. the approximation error can be measured by anything else. I don't care what the error measurement function is, as long as the measurement will represent the lost information. And by represent, I mean if $F$ will be able to recover $n$ from the measured error. And note that variables taken by $F$ are in $x$ decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I find your concept absurd.

Taken to its logical conclusion you could store petabytes of data in a single byte. No problem, because with the ingenious algorithm you want us to supply, you could still recover it!

If such an algorithm existed, all the storage companies would have gone bust. The fact is that if you record $n$ to 1000 decimal places, but only store 5 decimal places - as you suggest in the comments - then the stored information would be useless for recovering the other 995 decimal places.

If such an algorithm existed it would not be limited to numerical data. You could convert all data to numerical data using standard algorithms and then use your magic algorithm.

Of course, significant compression **is routinely used** for storing image data, video data etc. But that is because the encoding schemes routinely used for displaying or manipulating such data are extremely inefficient. So one can often get compression up to 5-10x.

If you gave me 3.14159 and asked me to recover the next thousand digits, of course I could do it on the assumption that you had given me the first six digits of $\pi$. Similarly if you have me the first 20 words of a famous book or play, I could no doubt supply the rest. But for general data, where nothing is known about what was stored except the few bytes you did store, you cannot hope to recover the missing data.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you understand my question. But I'm currently reading some articles on approximation with continued fraction. When I find a solution, continued fraction or not, I think I may have to provide a different answer to my question myself. Thanks again. I mean the appreciation.

Comment: @NairaWad ;Happy reading. Continuous fractions are a fascinating subject. Of course, there are ways of storing a 1000 digit number that use less space than storing it as 1000 ASCII digits. For certain **types** of number switching to continued fractions might save space - just as it is much better to store 7/13 in that form than with 1000 decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks again. I'd also appreciate some good recommendations in terms of articles and books on continued fraction.

Comment: @NairaWad [see this qu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754437/any-good-books-for-studying-continued-fraction) The Khinchin book is good.

Comment: @NairaWad [More offbeat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754437/any-good-books-for-studying-continued-fraction)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I won't be accepting your answer, but thanks. I will look into the problem and possibly answer the question in the near future I hope.

Comment: The link to the book is broken on the stackoverflow post your linked to. :(. Thanks anyway, I will search the book by its name.